# Hide a paragraph on the main page, but show it in the post on Tumblr

Tags: html, tumblr

I do not know if this is easy or standard. I would like to be able to put a tag around a paragraph so that the paragraph is invisible in the main page of a tumblr account, but visible in the post.

A little bit similar conceptually to the [READ MORE] idea, except it just takes out a single paragraph.

My objective (in case there is a better way out there), is to have navigation at the top of the post (above the first paragraph), but for that navigation not to show in the main page where all the posts are listed.

From reading on the web (eg [here](http://jeromyanglim.tumblr.com/post/33631210689/how-to-hide-body-of-posts-on-home-page-and-tag)), it seems that {block:PermalinkPage} can be used to hide text everywhere except the page. So I would either need to create a structure (e.g.  or something) inside the html background that takes advantage of this (I don't know if this is possible), or do something similar with code in the actual post.

Comment: Do you have any code for us to look at? Or do you know if there is a class that is added to the html / body tag that you could use to target?

Comment: @Minum, I do not have any code. I could edit the html in the post, but I'm afraid I do not know enough to even structure the question effectively? Hoping for some direction from someone with experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. If you want to create a text post with a paragraph hidden on the index page of your theme, then this should help:

Add this inside of the CSS of your theme code:

```
{block:IndexPage}
.hiddentext {display:none;}
{/block:IndexPage}
```

Create or edit the text post in HTML mode, and style the text you want to hide liked this:

```
<p>This is text that you will see!</p>

<p class="hiddentext">This text will only be visible on the permalink page!</p>
```

The text will display normally on the dashboard and on the permalink page of your blog, but will be invisible on the index page of your blog.

If you don't know where to add the css, go into your them HTML and search for `</style>` and place the code directly **above** that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting this navigation to show up on all post pages, and not show on the main page, you should put the navigation in your html and wrap it in `{block:PermalinkPage}` and `{/block:PermalinkPage}`. If you do not want this to show up on ask pages, and pages you create yourself (only post pages), instead wrap the html in `{block:Date}` and `{/block:Date}`.

You would put this somewhere after `{block:Post}` and before `{/block:Post}`, but without seeing your code, I can't be more precise.

Comment: Still on my to do! I will post back

Comment: My html doesn't have a {block:Post} segment.

Comment: Well to display posts it has to be there somewhere. Perhaps upload your theme code to pastebin so I can have a look and give you more specific help.

Comment: Your theme has `{block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="800"}`. I would advise putting the content you want just below `<div class="blog-post-content {PostType}">` and wrap it in `{block:PermalinkPage}` and `{/block:PermalinkPage}`